# Cant change default program for opening custom files

Tags: c++, exe, default-programs

I have compiled a C++ program that reads custom `.lang` files. Right now, the program prompts the user asking to enter the file and it opens.

I want the program to run when a file with the extension `.lang` is clicked. I have set the exe to be able to open `.lang` files with the Command Prompt. I am then trying to set the default program for `.lang` to this exe, but it does not change, but does not show any errors.

[image: A link to the default extension im setting]

Comment: Could you please share some part of the code .

Comment: Right now i just want the exe to run when a file with the .lang extension is clicked, will you still need to look at the code? its quite a large file

Comment: *I have set the exe to be able to open .lang files with the Command Prompt.* how? And how did you manage to get two identical extensions (`.lang` x 2) into that list in the picture?

Comment: Read MSDN's documentation: [Implementing a Custom File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper), in particular [Registering a File Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-file-types#registering-a-file-type)

Comment: Im not really sure at all how i got 2. To set the exe to be able to open .lang files, i use the command prompt command `assoc .lang=C:\Users\PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CPlusPlusProject\Debug\CPlusPlusProject.exe`

Comment: `assoc` can't be used in that way. It expects a `<FileType>` behind `=`, not the path to an executable.

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks, i understand now but how can i make **.lang** open the executable?

Comment: @MezzaMan Please see the links, Remy Lebeau posted as a comment.